# selenium execute_script only returns plain list

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

```
self.driver.get(self.DEL_PINO)
        resp = self.driver.execute_script("""
            var targetDate = "20220325"
            var jcd = "01";
            var resp = [];
            url = '/rsv.selectTimeScd.dp/dmparse.dm';
            data = {"fRsvD":targetDate, "fJiyukCd":"01"};
            $('div.rsvTable tbody#rsvTableBody').html("");
            postAjax(url, data, function(result){
                var timesList = result.times;
                var rowcnt_this = 1;
                
                for(var i=0; i<timesList.length; i++) {
                    var rowcnt = timesList[i].rowcnt;
                    var label = timesList[i].rsLabel.replace(":", "시 ") + "분";
                    var btClass = '';
        
                    resp.push("javascript:setFdata('"+jcd+"','"+timesList[i].fRsvD+"','"+timesList[i].fRsvT+"','"+timesList[i].fRsvDv+"', '"+timesList[i].fGubunCd+"', '"+timesList[i].fSelfYn+"', '"+timesList[i].fRoundCode+"', '"+btClass+"','"+timesList[i].dcAmt+"','"+timesList[i].assn_ind_inwon+"','"+timesList[i].fGubunCode+"','"+timesList[i].fRoundInd+"','"+timesList[i].fAssnInd+"','"+timesList[i].fInTerms+"','"+timesList[i].fSelfCartYn+"');");
                
                    if(rowcnt_this == rowcnt)
                        rowcnt_this = 1;
                    else
                        rowcnt_this++;
                }
            });
            
            return resp;
        """)
        print(resp)
```

I am trying to get the reservation list of the website by execute_script. However, I always get the result of

```
[]
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Any errors showing up in console of browser?

Comment: you would need execute_async_script and resolve it in your callback to postAjax

Comment: I think I've changed execute_script into execute_async_script however, it doesn't work. It only returns the value of {}

Comment: when I console.log() I get the right value